# Phoenix: value is not retrieved in view

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I would like to get teams value in template.
I can't get teams values. QUERY is OK.
Error message is blow.

ArgumentError at GET /members/new
assign @teams not available in eex template.
Please make sure all proper assigns have been set. If this
is a child template, ensure assigns are given explicitly by
the parent template as they are not automatically forwarded.

Is anything wrong?

member_controller.ex

```
  def new(conn, _params) do
    changeset = Member.changeset(%Member{})
    teams = Repo.all(Team)
    assign(conn, :teams, teams)
    render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
  end
```

form.html.eex

```
<%= @teams %>
```

Comment: `conn = assign(conn, :teams, teams)`?

Comment: 1) See @Dogbert 's comment.
2) To get/use the teams in your template do this: `@conn.assigns[:teams]`
There's no extra @teams variable. To do so, you needs to put it through like you do it with the changeset variable (`teams: teams`) in the render function to your template. Do the same from your template to your partials (`teams: @teams`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elixir is an immutable language. When you do `assign(conn, :teams, team)` the `conn` itself is not modified, instead a new, updated one is returned.
The fix would be to do:

```
def new(conn, _params) do
  changeset = Member.changeset(%Member{})
  teams = Repo.all(Team)
  conn = assign(conn, :teams, teams)
  render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
end
```

This can be further cleaned up with use of the pipeline operator:

```
def new(conn, _params) do
  changeset = Member.changeset(%Member{})
  teams = Repo.all(Team)
  conn
  |> assign(:teams, teams)
  |> render("new.html", changeset: changeset)
end
```

Comment: I understand what you told me. But It has not working, yet. Are there different mistake I have? Error "assign @teams not available in eex template." happens.

Comment: It seems "@teams" not available in form.html.eex. How can I give the "@teams" as parameter to form.html.eex template?

Comment: If you're rendering a partial, you need to pass all the assigns in the `render` call, so probably something like `render("form.html", teams: @teams)`

Answer (score 0):

I think the above code can modified as

```
def new(conn, _params) do
  changeset = Member.changeset(%Member{})
  teams = Repo.all(Team)
  render("new.html", changeset: changeset, teams: teams)
end
```